# Не запускается автоматически сеть, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

Проблема появилась после переноса Ubuntu 20.04 с virtual box на VMware, проблема заключается в том что после перезагрузки ОС не поднимается сеть, приходится запускать вручную через команду dhclient -v, после этого пинг начинает идти и получается подключится удаленно

Comment: попробуй сделать скрипт и выполнить его либо через crontab либо с помощью файла /etc/rc.d/rc.local.
можешь прочитать [тут](https://itsecforu.ru/2020/05/13/%F0%9F%90%A7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80/)

Comment: да, спасибо, решило проблему, но это конечно как временный костыль

Answer (score 2):

20.04 скорее всего настраивалась через ifupdown исправьте имя интерфейса в /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: По этому пути у меня вообще нет interfaces :(

Comment: тогда остается nm. запусти nmtui

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего поменялся сетевой интерфейс(interface) при переносе

какие есть интерфейсы в системе можно глянуть командой

```
ip -br a
```

или

```
ip -br l
```

они будут перечислены в первой колонке, допустим нужный интерфейс это `ens33`, тогда

---

**Вариант 1** *(не валидно для ubuntu 20.04)*

**dhclient** пробует запускать старый сервис по типу `dhclient@interface.service`

```
systemctl start dhclient@ens33.service
```

для добавление в автозагрузку

```
systemctl enable dhclient@ens33.service
```

---

**Вариант 2**

использовать **systemd-networkd** который является частью **systemd**, то есть устанавливать его не нужно.

создаём файл `/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network` с таким содержимым

```
[Match]
Name=ens33

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

запустить

```
systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

добавить в автозагрузку

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

посмотреть статус можно командой

```
networkctl
```

Comment: по запросу `ip -br a` я получаю вот такой список:

`lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
ens33            UP             192.168.0.14/23 fe80::250:56ff:fe23:c975/64`


далее ввожу `systemctl enable dhclient@ens33.service` и получаю:
`Failed to enable unit: Unit file dhclient@ens33.service does not exist.`

Comment: @Леонид похоже что service для dhclient не завезли, тогда можно накостылить по типу этого - [How to configure the Ubuntu DHCP client](https://linuxhint.com/configure-ubuntu-dhcp-client/) или использовать тот же встроенный механизм по типу **systemd-networkd** (допишу в ответе)